# Power query- Error when reading shared folder

Tags: powerquery, importerror

for a couple of weeks now im facing the following problem and have absolutely no
clue why my import isn´t working anymore.
Im using power query to read documents within a network folder. More specifically the the m function "File.Contents". For some unknown reasons this ain´t possible anymore and the following error message is thrown:

"Unexpected error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Details:
Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. --->  ..... "

This is especially puzzling for me since i can read/import single files within that folder without any problem (by using the function "Exel.Workbook .." for instance"). Does anybody know how to fix that problem and why this has occured? I would really appreciate any help since reading all files individually is not a scalable option to me and reading the entire folder was possible in the past.
Thanks for your help in advance !!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its already the first line of code:  File.Contents("Y:\....."), which  produces this error. Using the Excel GUI it fails when calling Data> Get Data >From File > From Folder after I inserted the link.